# How to set a model to destroy only if there is no child?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My solution is to find all the child table for the id of the parent , if not that destroy. Is there another way better that this? use has_many's options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need count if there are child. Not fetch him. There are no solution to do.

Answer (score 2):

If your database supports it, you can declare a [foreign key constraint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) on the schema.

Comment: I do add a foreign key already :options => "CONSTRAINT fk_item_image REFERENCES item(id)" , but how do I make it to check the child before delete ?

Comment: Assuming you're using MySql, you need to create your tables with the InnoDB storage engine. See examples [over here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html).